# React useeffect hook

Tags: reactjs, axios, react-hooks

I'm having the following error when using hooks for fetching data.
I have two functional componentes

```
function TopTen() {
    const [topTen, setTopten] = useState([]);  
    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true); 
    const [error, setError] = useState(false); 

    useEffect(() => {         
        console.log("useEffect TopTen has been called!");   
        const fetchdata = async () => {
        const response = await api.topTen();  // this calls axios(url)
        setLoading(false);
        setTopten(response.data);    
        setError(response.error);    
    };

    fetchdata ();     
}, []);

  return ( 
        {topTen.length > 0 &&
        <Table 
          tableData={topTen.map((item, idx) => {
            return ([
              item.name
            ]);
          })}
        /> 
        }
    )

}

function Declaraciones() {

    // ... here I'm using other effects also for fetching data 
    const [data, setData] = useState([]);

    useEffect(() => {            
        const fetchData = async () => {
        const response = await api.fetch();
    //...
        };

        fetchData ();     
    }, []);

    return (

        <div>
            <p>{data}</p>
            <TopTen />
        </div>
    )

}
```

For some reason sometimes TopTen component works fine and sometimes don't. It's like random. 
What I see is that api calls returns fake data like "cached" so when trying to map the result it fails:

```
**TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined**
```

Maybe i'm missing the concept of useeffect hooks.

Does anyone knows how can I fix this?

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure that your backend sends consistent schema each time as response?

Comment: @UtsavPatel yes I'm testing my backend API with postman and its OK. Weird thing is that sometimes when sending request from the frontend it returns good results and some other bad results. I don't know why. I'm debbugging the axios request and apparently it's fine

Comment: When bad data is returned, it belongs to another get request I'm doing before/after, like

request 1 => data 1
request 2 => data 2 --- here my backend returns data 1 
request 3 => data 3

Answer (score 0):

You have to convert the response to json with await response.json();
and then use setState.

```
useEffect(() => {         
        console.log("useEffect TopTen has been called!");   
        const fetchdata = async () => {
        const response = await api.topTen();  // this calls axios(url)
        const responseData = await response.json();
        setLoading(false);
        setTopten(responseData.data);    
        setError(responseData.error);    
    };

    fetchdata ();     
}, []);
```

Comment: I've tried using both axios and fetch, now I'm getting good results but I don't know why sometimes they return bad data
    `
    const result = await fetch('/api/path/top');        
    const json = await result.json();
    response.data = json; 
    const result2 = await axios.get('/api/path/top'); 
    response.data2 = result2.data;
`

Answer (score 0):

try :

```
setTopten(response.data.filter(function(val){ return val!==undefined; }))
```